# Crop an image on node.js

Tags: node.js

I have an image uploaded to my server I'll like to crop it without user interaction (I already know the x,y and width and height of the section to crop).

Which library should I use?
Can anyone provide a simple sample?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you the magnific npm module **[imagemagick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick)**

With imagemagick, you can crop an image like that:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.crop({
  srcPath: path,
  dstPath: 'cropped.jpg',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  quality: 1,
  gravity: "North"
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  // foo
});
```